# Is there any known value of the infinite sum $\sum_{m=1,n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{(m^2+n^2)^2}$?

Tags: sequences-and-series, number-theory, analytic-number-theory

Let $L=\{m+in\hspace{1mm}|\hspace{1mm}m,n\in \mathbb{Z}\}$. I was trying to find out the value of $\sum_{w\in L\setminus \{0\}}^\infty\frac{1}{w^4}$ where I encountered the infinite sum $\sum_{m=1,n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{(m^2+n^2)^2}$. Any idea to approach this will help a lot.

Comment: You might find all that you need [HERE](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/DoubleSeries.html).  The answer is $2\beta(2)\zeta(2)$.

Comment: See Eisenstein series $G_4$.

Comment: That is what I was trying to compute for the simplest of lattice in $\mathbb{C}$ possible. However it turns out to be a tough job almost impossible.

Comment: Thank you very much @MarkViola

Comment: Certainly not impossible, if one is willing to look up a book treating Eisenstein series - see the nice answer!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since $\mathbb{Z}[i]$ is a UFD we have that for any $n\in\mathbb{N}$ the function
$$ r_2(n) = \left|\{(a,b)\in\mathbb{Z}^2: a^2+b^2=n\}\right| $$
is given by $4(\chi_4*1)(n)$, with $\chi_4$ being the non-principal Dirichlet character $\!\!\pmod{4}$ and $*$ being the Dirichlet (multiplicative) [convolution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet_convolution). In particular
$$ \sum_{\substack{(a,b)\in\mathbb{Z}^2\\(a,b)\neq(0,0)}}\frac{1}{(a^2+b^2)^s} =\sum_{n\geq 1}\frac{r_2(n)}{n^s}=4\,\zeta(s)\,L(\chi_4,s)$$
holds for any $s>1$. This leads to
$$ \sum_{\substack{(a,b)\in\mathbb{Z}^2\\(a,b)\neq(0,0)}}\frac{1}{(a^2+b^2)^2}=4\zeta(2)\sum_{n\geq 0}\left[\frac{1}{(4n+1)^2}-\frac{1}{(4n+3)^2}\right]= \frac{2}{3}\pi^2 G$$ 
where $G$ is [Catalan's constant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Catalan%27s_constant). In particular
$$ \sum_{a,b\geq 1}\frac{1}{(a^2+b^2)^2}=\color{red}{G\,\zeta(2)-\zeta(4)}\approx 0.4243797762. $$
Here $L(\chi_4,s)$ stands for $\sum_{n\geq 1}\frac{\chi_4(n)}{n^s}$. Different proofs of $r_2(n)=4(\chi_4*1)(n)$ (a combinatorial proof through quadratic forms and double-counting and an analytic proof through [Jacobi triple product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jacobi_triple_product)) can be found in *D.H. Cox - Primes of the form $x^2+ny^2$*.

Comment: Hi Jack.  You might consider mentioning the definition of $L(\cdot,\cdot)$ and provide a reference to some of the claims throughout.

Comment: @MarkViola: done.